# Install Firefox 5 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, web, packages

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, and, for web development, need to install Firefox 5 specifically.  I know I can do it by hand from the Mozilla download.  But I'd like a Ubuntu package.  Is one available? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the [firefox 5 deb](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/1778093/+listing-archive-extra) from the [Ubuntu Mozilla Security Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ppa) for Ubuntu 11.04 (should also work under 11.10).
Beware, it will replace your current firefox package. You would need to find a specific firefox-5 package.

You may also be interested in [cross browser testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565505/whats-the-best-way-to-do-cross-browser-testing).